# Wordpress plugin compatibility problems

Tags: wordpress, plugins, compatibility

How can i fix this problem? It literally displays on the site as well while loading... Everything seems to be working though so i am not sure what's wrong...[this is the issue displays in wp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8jJu.png)

Comment: To help people respond to your question quickly, it's best to just include error messages as text (perhaps as a block quote) in the question. This also helps people find this question (and hopefully an answer) by searching.

Answer (score 0):

I Googled this error and it can be [fixed by uninstalling and reinstalling the Divi theme](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-update-issue-with-product-variable/).

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work... I still have the same error line even though i reinstalled the divi theme...

Comment: What happens if you turn off all other plugins?